# Como puedo hacer un login en Android y SQLite

Tags: java, android

Como puedo hacer un login  ya que me saca de la aplicación cuando intento ingresar con un usuario registrado.

Este es mi código:

```java
//Metodo para el boton iniciar sesion

public void InciarSesion (View vista1){
    BasedeDatos admin = new BasedeDatos(this, "Usuarios",null,1 );
    SQLiteDatabase basededatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String email = txtemail.getText().toString();
    String password = txtpassword.getText().toString();

    if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
        Cursor fila = basededatos.rawQuery("Select Correo, Password from Usuarios where Correo= " + email + "and Password=" + password,null);

        if (fila.moveToFirst()){
            Intent login = new Intent(this, CinePrime.class);
            startActivity(login);
            basededatos.close();
        }else{

            Toast.makeText( this, "No se encontraron datos del usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            basededatos.close();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText( this, "Debes introducir un correo y una contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: es que me saca de la aplicacion cuando intento ingesar con un usuario registrado

Comment: se me hace que el error lo tengo aqui Cursor fila = basededatos.rawQuery("Select Correo, Password from Usuarios where Correo= " + email + "and Password=" + password,null);

Comment: Revisa el Logcat y agrega el texto completo del mensaje de error en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Aprende a depurar tu programa, Android Studio tiene herramientas de depuración que te ahorrarán mucho tiempo y muchos rompederos de cabeza.

Comment: es que no se como hacer eso no soy programador soy QBP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes usar las comillas sencillas (`'`) como contenedor de las cadenas al realizar la consulta para las variables `email` y `password`,

> "Select Correo, Password from Usuarios where Correo= '" + email + "'
> and Password='" + password + "'"

realiza lo siguiente:

```
Cursor fila = basededatos.rawQuery("Select Correo, Password from Usuarios where Correo= '" + email + "' and Password='" + password + "'",null);
```